# Easiest way to implement spellchecker for IE

Tags: spell-checking

I'm using ASP.NET webforms and lots of javascript/jQuery.  I'm looking for a really simple and easy way to implement spell checking for a single text area in IE (since all the other browsers implement their own spell checking).  I usually stay away from IE specific technologies but I'm willing to make an exception since I only need the feature in IE (6,7,8).

Gmail's spellchecker is nice.  Hotmail's spellchecker is amazing (only works in IE) although it doesn't seem multi-lingual.  I'd love to find an easy to have the same feature.

Telling my customer to download a plugin for their browser is not an option.

I'm looking for a really quick implementation. The only feature I really want is multilingual.

Suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://spellerpages.sourceforge.net/

```
<!-- Source the JavaScript spellChecker object -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="spellChecker.js">
</script>

<!-- Call a function like this to handle the spell check command -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function openSpellChecker() {
    // get the textarea we're going to check
    var txt = document.myform.mytextarea;
    // give the spellChecker object a reference to our textarea
    // pass any number of text objects as arguments to the constructor:
    var speller = new spellChecker( txt );
    // kick it off
    speller.openChecker();
}
</script>
```

The demo for this is no longer available.